# Angular removesAt only removes other controls through first control from FormArray

Tags: angular

```js
    createAssignmentForm = this.fb.group({
      
      questions: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.group({
          content: [
            '',
            [Validators.required('Please provide assignment name.')],
          ],
          testcases: this.fb.array([
            this.fb.group({
              input: [
                '',
                [Validators.required('Please enter input for this test case.')],
              ],
              output: [
                '',
                [
                  Validators.required(
                    'Please enter output for this test case.'
                  ),
                ],
              ],
            }),
          ]),
        }),
      ]),
    })}
```

Here's the form

```html
    <form [formGroup]="parentForm">
      <div formArrayName="questions">
                <div
                  class="form-control grid grid-cols-2 justify-between mb-8 w-xl"
                  *ngFor="let testcase of getTestcaseControl(i); index as i"
                  [formGroupName]="i"
                >
                  <div class="flex">
                    <div class="form-control m-0">
                      <label class="label">
                        <span class="label-text">Inputs</span>
                      </label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="2 3 4"
             
                        formControlName="input"
                      />
                      <label class="label">
                        <p
                          *ngIf="checkFormInput(testcase, 'input')"
                          class="invalid-feedback"
                        >
                          Please enter input for this test case.
                        </p>
                      </label>
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="form-control m-0">
                      <label class="label">
                        <span class="label-text">Outputs</span>
                      </label>
                      <div class="flex items-center">
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          placeholder="12 34 84"
                          formControlName="output"
                        />
    
                        <!-- delete icon -->
                        <img
                          src="../../../../assets/images/course/course-leaderboard-avatars/cancel.png"
                          class="w-6 h-6 cursor-pointer py-auto mt-2 mx-2"
                          alt="delete icon"
                          (click)="onDeleteTestcase(i)"
                        />
                      </div>
    
                      <label class="label">
                        <p
                          *ngIf="checkFormInput(testcase, 'output')"
                          class="invalid-feedback"
                        >
                          Please enter output for this test case.
                        </p>
                      </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
    
                  <div class="form-control m-0 w-6"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex justify-end mr-4">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="onAddTestcase(i)">
                  Add More
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </form>
```

`parentForm` here is `createAssignmentForm` passed down as Input to child component.

```js
     @Input()
      parentForm!: FormGroup;
    
      
      constructor(
        private assignmentService: AssignmentService,
        private fb: FormBuilder
      ) {}
    
      ngOnInit(): void {}
    
      onSubmit() {
        console.log('Hello');
      }
    
      onAddTestcase(index) {
        (<FormArray>(
          (<FormGroup>(<FormArray>this.parentForm.get('questions')).controls[index])
            .controls.testcases
        )).push(
          this.fb.group({
            input: [
              '',
              [Validators.required('Please enter input for this test case.')],
            ],
            output: [
              '',
              [Validators.required('Please enter output for this test case.')],
            ],
          })
        );
      }
    
     
      checkFormInput(testcase, checkFor: string) {
        let isInvalid = false;
        let isTouched = false;
        if (checkFor === 'input') {
          isInvalid = testcase.controls.input.invalid;
    
          isTouched = testcase.controls.input.touched;
        } else {
          isInvalid = testcase.controls.output.invalid;
    
          isTouched = testcase.controls.output.touched;
        }
    
        return isInvalid && isTouched;
      }
    
      getTestcaseControl(index) {
        // return (this.parentForm.get('questions.testcases') as FormArray).controls;
        console.log('test', <FormArray>this.parentForm.get('questions'));
        // return (<FormArray>(<FormGroup><unknown>(<FormArray>this.parentForm.get('questions'))).get('testcases')).controls
    
        return (<FormArray>(
          (<FormGroup>(<FormArray>this.parentForm.get('questions')).controls[index])
            .controls.testcases
        )).controls;
      }
    
      onDeleteTestcase(index: number) {
        (<FormArray>(
          (<FormGroup>(<FormArray>this.parentForm.get('questions')).controls[index])
            .controls.testcases
        )).removeAt(index);
      }
    
    }
```

As I add more more testcases controls - deleting the last results in `Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined` - Only way to delete the controls array is to delete through first control delete icon. Other control delete icon results in 'controls' of undefined.

[image: Problem]

Adding as it might be hard to understand the problem first, Here Add more button will add the controls of `testcases`, now I can only able to remove these created controls through first control "X" button, It doesn't remove control by it's individual "X" button (marked in circle) clicking that results in `Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake from my side, question itself is an array and in `onDeleteTestcase` I was passing the `testcase` loop index, and using it as an index for question and as well testcase, that's the reason only first control deleted successfully, and other's didn't cause that index (as of that time is 1) didn't existed on question array as there was only 1 question. I added the fixed version of `onDeleteTestcase`

```
  onDeleteTestcase(testcaseIndex: number, questionIndex: number) {
    if (testcaseIndex !== 0)
      (<FormArray>(
        (<FormGroup>(
          (<FormArray>this.parentForm.get('questions')).controls[questionIndex]
        )).controls.testcases
      )).removeAt(testcaseIndex);
  }
```